# Getting the completed task Id using Task.WaitAny()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I know that my goal can be achieved by using Task.WhenAny() but I will not deal with async await if I can avoid it, in order to prevent deadlocks. I have following code:

```
try
{
   Task.WaitAny(this.Tasks.ToArray());
   foreach (var task in this.Tasks)
   {
      if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
      {
         if (task.Exception.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
         {

         }
      }
   }                    
}  
catch (OperationCanceledException o)
{
   // Handling cancelled tasks
}              
catch (Exception e)
{
   // Handling faulted tasks
}
```

And I for instance want to know exactly the id of my task, which has faulted or the Id of my task which has been cancelled. I have tried to do so as shown in the try block above, but this is not a solution since it also will throw an exception for tasks that has been cancelled before. Can I obtain a solution for this problem using Task.WaitAny() ?.

Comment: Synchronously waiting on asynchronous operation (by using `WaitAny` instead of `WhenAny` is *exactly* how you cause deadlocks.  You avoid deadlocks by doing everything asynchronously all the way up the call stack.

Comment: But WaitAny is not an asynchronous operation as far as I know ?

Comment: Correct.  It's synchronously blocking on the asynchronous tasks that you have.  That's how you go about getting into deadlocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Task.WaitAny`:

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The index of the completed Task object in the tasks array.

So you can do this:

```
var taskIndex = Task.WaitAny(this.Tasks.ToArray());
var task = this.Tasks[taskIndex];
```